# Oracle: Update from within procedure not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, rdbms

In my Oracle PL/SQL procedure I am trying to update a row like this:

```
UPDATE personal p
SET p.surname = surname, p.name = name, p."alter" = alter, p.sex = sex, p.jobcode = jobcode, p.year_wage = month_wage * 12
WHERE p.personalnr = personalnr;
COMMIT;
```

I have added these two statements right after the commit to confirm the code is reached and executed with the right arguments (e.g. here I want to change the name):

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('updated ' || name);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('personalnr ' || personalnr);
```

Now this update-statement is part of a procedure that is called from within another procedure.

However, the changes are not applied and the name will remain the same even tho the update was executed. I have tried to use an exception-handler as well and there doesn't seem to be any exception happening. I can confirm that the `WHERE`-clause is as intendet. There is one record that matches the predicate.

Now the strange thing:
When I change the code to the example below, an update happens. However it updates *every* record and not only the one with the right personalnr. Again: the routine is called only once with one `personalnr` that matches only one entry in the table.

```
UPDATE personal p
SET p.name = 'test'
WHERE p.personalnr = personalnr;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working, but it's updating *all* rows in the table (or at least, those where `personalnr` is not null), not just the one you expect.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-A551A39D-7DF8-4525-BE0F-1F46FE04ED09):

> If a SQL statement references a name that belongs to both a column and either a local variable or formal parameter, then the column name takes precedence.

You have a PL/SQL variable that has the same name as a column. When you do

```
where p.personalnr = personalnr
```

you are really doing:

```
where p.personalnr = p.personalnr
```

and the same thing happens in the `set` part; `SET p.surname = surname` updates the column value to whatever value it had before, not the PL/SQL variable's value. So it *looks* like the update didn't happen- it actually did, but because everything was set to the same as it's original value it doesn't look like anything happened. (Except - all rows will now have the same `year_wage` value...)

You can either prefix your variables with the procedure name:

```
where p.personalnr = my_proc.personalnr
```

or change the variable names so they don't conflict; it's common to use a short prefix, e.g. `l_` for a local variable, or `p_` for a passed-in parameter, etc.

```
where p.personalnr = l_personalnr
```

Remember to do that for the `set` part too, or your update still won't appear to do anything.

```
UPDATE personal p
SET p.surname = l_surname, p.name = l_name, p."alter" = l_alter,
  p.sex = l_sex, p.jobcode = l_jobcode, p.year_wage = l_month_wage * 12
WHERE p.personalnr = l_personalnr;
```

Comment: this works, thanks. this almost drove me insane as i thought the 'p'-prefix would be descriptive enough to make the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the parameter name something other than the table's column name.

```
UPDATE personal p
SET p.name = 'test'
WHERE p.personalnr = personally; 
-- here condition is column_name = column_name
-- This will be true for all the records of the table
```

Change `personalnr --> p_personalnr` and it will work for you

Comment: this worked even tho it is a little irritating to me. thank you!