# PLS-00341: declaration of cursor 'cur2' is incomplete or malformed || PL/SQL: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I wrote a procedure where i am trying to insert value from source to destination table, i used bulk collect in order to execute large volume of data.

While executing the below procedure, its showing cursor cus2 declaration is incomplete and its showing  some column ambiguously defined in the cursor.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST2 (
    p_array_size IN NUMBER
) IS

CURSOR cur1 IS SELECT DISTINCT
        *
                        FROM
        test
                        
        
        CURSOR cur3 IS SELECT * FROM test;
        
        CURSOR cur2(BND_TYPE cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.bndng_typ%TYPE, BND_VAL cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.bndng_val%TYPE, FINANCIAL_INST_ID cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.financial_institution_id%TYPE, 
          PRDCT_ID cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.prdct_id%TYPE,PRDCT_SUB_ID cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.prdct_sub_id%TYPE, INSTRUMENT_ID cr_loan_prima_rate_orig.instrmnt_id%TYPE) IS SELECT
                                d.*
                                FROM
                                test1 d,
                                (
                                    SELECT
                                    b.prdct_id,
                                    
                                    FROM
                                        test2 a,
                                        test1 b
                                    WHERE
                                        a.ir_id = b.ir_id
                                        AND   a.price_component_id = b.price_component_id
                                        AND   a.financial_institution_id = b.financial_institution_id
                                    GROUP BY
                                        b.prdct_id,
                                        
                                ) e
                                WHERE
                                d.prdct_id = e.prdct_id
                                AND   d.bndng_typ = BND_TYPE
                                AND   d.bndng_val = BND_VAL
                                AND   d.financial_institution_id = FINANCIAL_INST_ID
                                AND   d.prdct_id = PRDCT_ID
                                AND   d.prdct_sub_id = PRDCT_SUB_ID
                                AND   d.instrmnt_id = INSTRUMENT_ID  ;
                                
                                
        
        TYPE loan_data_tbl IS TABLE OF cur1%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
        loan_data loan_data_tbl;
        
        TYPE loanrate_tbl IS TABLE OF cur2%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
        loan_rate loanrate_tbl;
        
        BEGIN 
        
            DECLARE
                v_noofDays NUMBER:=0;
                currentDt DATE;
            BEGIN 
                    SELECT * INTO  currentDt FROM dt;
                    
                    BEGIN
                    
                        IF cur1%Isopen Then
                            Close cur1;
                        End IF;
                        
                        IF cur2%Isopen Then
                            Close cur2;
                        End IF;
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        OPEN cur1;
                        LOOP
                                FETCH cur1 BULK COLLECT INTO loan_data LIMIT p_array_size;
                                EXIT WHEN loan_data.COUNT = 0;
                                
                                FOR i IN 1..loan_data.COUNT         
                                LOOP
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                             OPEN cur3;
                                        
                                    OPEN cur2(loan_data(i).bndng_typ, loan_data(i).bndng_val,loan_data(i).financial_institution_id,
                                    loan_data(i).prdct_id, loan_data(i).prdct_sub_id, loan_data(i).instrmnt_id);
                                             loop
                                        
                                    FETCH cur2 BULK COLLECT INTO loan_rate LIMIT p_array_size;
                                    EXIT WHEN loan_rate.COUNT = 0;
                                    
                                    FOR j IN 1..loan_rate.COUNT
                                    LOOP 
                                    
                                        IF(cur3.POS_NUM = loan_data(i).POS_NUM AND cur3.POS_TYPE = loan_data(i).POS_TYPE    
                                            AND cur3.PRICE_COMPONENT_ID = loan_rate(j).PRICE_COMPONENT_ID
                                            AND cur3.RPRTD_TILL_DT = loan_data(i).RPRTD_TILL_DT) THEN 
                                        
                                            update test SET SEQ_NUM=1,
                                                WHERE SEQ_NUM=2;
                                                
                                        ELSE 
                                        
                                            INSERT INTO test VALUES (
                                            ....
                                            ....
                                            
                                        );
                                                  
                                             END IF;
                                        COMMIT;                     
                                    END LOOP;
                                END LOOP;
                                
                            CLOSE cur2;
                        CLOSE cur1;
                        
                    END LOOP;
                         END LOOP;
            
            CLOSE cur1;
        END;
    END;    
End ;
/
```

For me everything looks good, not able to find the exact mistake.can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: there's a ';' missing at the end of declaration of your first cursor.

Comment: The `d.prdct_id = PRDCT_ID` is causing the other error, and isn't doing what you think. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62595708/266304) which was about essentially the same issue.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but if you use implicit cursor processing your code will automatically bulk collect. Instead of an explicit open/fetch/close, use code like `for cur3_row in cur3 loop`.

Comment: Formatting your code would make it easier to follow the structure. Four levels of looping seems a lot, and committing in loops is generally not recommended - if you must, couldn't it be in the outermost (bulk collect) one?  Also you only need one `begin - end` - I would get rid of the others and have all the declarations together at the top.

Comment: Some of the cursor parameters have the same names as columns, so you should either use a naming convention (such as camelCase or `cp_` prefix) or else explicitly prefix them with the cursor name e.g. `d.prdct_sub_id = cur2.prdct_sub_id` to avoid the issue @AlexPoole mentioned.